# Error while trying to read an Excel file

Tags: java

When I run the code below:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
public Properties getObjectRepository() throws IOException{
 //Read object repository file
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties")));
     //load all objects
p.load(stream);
return p;
}
```

It shows error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at uioperation.Excel_object.getObjectRepository(Excel_object.java:14)
    at ExecuteTestcase.Testcase_execute.main(Testcase_execute.java:27)
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: make sure the path is correct and the file "object.properties" is available.

Comment: There is no Property with the key `"D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties"` I guess. in `getProperty` you do not specify the property file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that you have a System property called `D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties`

so

change to

```
new File("D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties"));
```

assuming that this file does exist

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code for setting the property is not implemented, But you can simply Open a file using following code.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
public Properties getObjectRepository() throws IOException{
    //Read object repository file

    String FileName="Path to your file"; 
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    //load all objects
    p.load(stream);
    return p;
}
```

Or otherwise, you should get it from system properties..

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
public Properties getObjectRepository() throws IOException{
    //Read object repository file

    String FileName=System.getProperty("Prperty Key for your file path"); // the property should ave been already set somewhere in the code before execution of this line
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    //load all objects
    p.load(stream);
    return p;
}
```

This is for setting the property and accessing the file

```
Properties p = new Properties();
public Properties getObjectRepository() throws IOException{

    //Set Property for file path

    setProperty("filePath","D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties");
    //Read object repository file

   String FileName=System.getProperty("filePath"); //now fileName is similar to "D:\\src\\objects\\object.properties"
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    //load all objects
    p.load(stream);
    return p;
}
```